# Cookie logging in access logs with Google Cloud CDN/Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-cdn

We are trying to move one of our sites from AWS to GCP.

We have a site that currently sits on AWS, with Cloudfront backed by Application Load balancer as its origin. AWS does provide an option to log cookies in access logs, which we are using in some of our data processing services.

I'm trying to implement the same with Google cloud services, using Google CDN/Load Balancer, but I cant seem to find a way to do it. [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#HttpRequest) was also not of much help, as it does not tell on how to do it, or if it even is possible.

Can someone help me with this? Is it even possible to log cookie data in Google Cloud?

Comment: Cloud CDN currently logs cookieless tokens in the request URL, but does not log tokens or signed requests encapsulated in cookies.You can raise a feature request in this [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to log cookies or custom headers in the GCLB (CDN) logs today.

Using the Media CDN service, it is possible to log custom attributes using Service Extensions (Proxy-WASM) to capture the custom log attributes and then merge them with the base Media CDN logs.